# 'Couldn't load Spacy model for any of languages: en' works fine locally but issue when deploying on heroku

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, deployment, spacy

having issue with Spacy (used by Profanity Filter), worked fine on local host but encounter this issue when deploying on Heroku, will post Heroku logs below:

```
2021-04-09T00:13:06.393111+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2021-04-09T00:13:06.393141+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2021-04-09T00:13:06.393578+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2021-04-09T00:13:06.393608+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2021-04-09T00:13:06.394070+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2021-04-09T00:13:06.394098+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2021-04-09T00:13:06.394484+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2021-04-09T00:13:06.394515+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2021-04-09T00:13:06.395013+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2021-04-09T00:13:06.395207+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2021-04-09T00:13:06.476860+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-09T00:13:06.557154+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-04-09T00:13:11.794584+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=aniroku.herokuapp.com request_id=686eea88-4a27-464c-a946-1d0af3050f0a fwd="98.248.138.150" dyno=web.1 connect=5000ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-09T00:14:05.973648+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-04-09T00:14:16.176963+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2021-04-09T00:14:19.480591+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-09 00:14:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-04-09T00:14:19.481348+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-09 00:14:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:27310 (4)
2021-04-09T00:14:19.482508+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-09 00:14:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-04-09T00:14:19.490234+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-09 00:14:19 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2021-04-09T00:14:19.569114+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-09 00:14:19 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2021-04-09T00:14:20.151760+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390074+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-09 00:14:27 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390108+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390111+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390112+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390112+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390112+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390113+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390113+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390114+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390115+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390115+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390115+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390116+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390116+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390117+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390117+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390118+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390119+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390119+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390120+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390120+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390121+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390121+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390122+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390122+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 38, in <module>
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390122+00:00 app[web.1]: pf = ProfanityFilter()
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390124+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/profanity_filter/profanity_filter.py", line 138, in __init__
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390124+00:00 app[web.1]: self.config(
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390124+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/profanity_filter/profanity_filter.py", line 175, in config
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390125+00:00 app[web.1]: self._set_languages(languages, load_morphs=morphs is None, load_nlps=nlps is None, load_spells=spells is None)
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390125+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/profanity_filter/profanity_filter.py", line 430, in _set_languages
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390126+00:00 app[web.1]: self.nlps = None
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390126+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/profanity_filter/profanity_filter.py", line 349, in nlps
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390126+00:00 app[web.1]: raise ProfanityFilterError(f"Couldn't load Spacy model for any of languages: {self.languages_str}")
2021-04-09T00:14:27.390127+00:00 app[web.1]: profanity_filter.types_.ProfanityFilterError: Couldn't load Spacy model for any of languages: en
2021-04-09T00:14:27.394479+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-09 00:14:27 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395242+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-09 00:14:27 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395242+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395243+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395243+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395244+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395244+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395244+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395245+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395245+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395245+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395246+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395246+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395246+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395247+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395247+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395247+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395248+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395250+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395250+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395251+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395251+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395251+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395252+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395252+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395252+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 38, in <module>
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395253+00:00 app[web.1]: pf = ProfanityFilter()
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395253+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/profanity_filter/profanity_filter.py", line 138, in __init__
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395253+00:00 app[web.1]: self.config(
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395254+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/profanity_filter/profanity_filter.py", line 175, in config
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395255+00:00 app[web.1]: self._set_languages(languages, load_morphs=morphs is None, load_nlps=nlps is None, load_spells=spells is None)
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395255+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/profanity_filter/profanity_filter.py", line 430, in _set_languages
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395255+00:00 app[web.1]: self.nlps = None
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395256+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/profanity_filter/profanity_filter.py", line 349, in nlps
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395256+00:00 app[web.1]: raise ProfanityFilterError(f"Couldn't load Spacy model for any of languages: {self.languages_str}")
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395262+00:00 app[web.1]: profanity_filter.types_.ProfanityFilterError: Couldn't load Spacy model for any of languages: en
2021-04-09T00:14:27.395688+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-09 00:14:27 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2021-04-09T00:14:27.642013+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=aniroku.herokuapp.com request_id=b060bda8-7d95-4916-8ae7-0e2c40e04545 fwd="98.248.138.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6766ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-04-09T00:14:27.660896+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-09 00:14:27 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 7 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-04-09T00:14:27.744663+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-09 00:14:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-04-09T00:14:27.744855+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-09 00:14:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-04-09T00:14:27.860219+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-04-09T00:14:27.943608+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-04-09T00:14:33.273100+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=aniroku.herokuapp.com request_id=6a90333d-1254-44c6-98b9-4bcb953ba60d fwd="98.248.138.150" dyno=web.1 connect=5000ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Also my requirements file:

```
bcrypt==3.2.0
blinker==1.4
blis==0.7.4
cached-property==1.5.2
catalogue==1.0.0
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.5
chardet==4.0.0
click==7.1.2
cymem==2.0.5
dnspython==2.1.0
email-validator==1.1.2
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1.tar.gz
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-DebugToolbar==0.11.0
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
greenlet==1.0.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==2.10
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
more-itertools==8.7.0
murmurhash==1.0.5
numpy==1.20.2
ordered-set==3.1.1
ordered-set-stubs==0.1.3
packaging==20.9
pathy==0.4.0
plac==1.1.3
poetry-version==0.1.5
preshed==3.0.5
profanity-filter==1.3.3
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
pycparser==2.20
pydantic==1.7.3
pyparsing==2.4.7
redis==3.5.3
requests==2.25.1
ruamel.yaml==0.15.100
six==1.15.0
smart-open==3.0.0
spacy==2.3.5
spacy-legacy==3.0.2
SQLAlchemy==1.4.6
srsly==1.0.5
thinc==7.4.5
tomlkit==0.5.11
tqdm==4.60.0
typer==0.3.2
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.26.4
wasabi==0.8.2
Werkzeug==1.0.1
WTForms==2.3.3
```

from my app file:

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm

pf = ProfanityFilter()
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
profanity_filter = ProfanityFilter(nlps={'en': nlp})  
nlp.add_pipe(profanity_filter.spacy_component, last=True)
```

Could also be other issues in my deployment logs, but trying to tackle one issue at a time, thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 1):

This requirement installs the model as `en_core_web_sm` but does not add the `en` symlink.

```
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1.tar.gz
```

You can add the symlink with:

```sh
python -m spacy link en_core_web_sm en
```

Comment: Link is successful, but still produces same error when trying to open the app.